# For which algebraic categories A is [Top,A] pointed

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory

I've been studying basic category theory and algebraic topology and became interested in this question. To repeat the title, for which algebraic categories $\mathbf{A}$, is the functor category $[\mathrm{Top},\mathbf{A}]$ pointed? 
Here algebraic category may be interpreted in the sense of universal algebra i.e. category with objects algebras of same signature $\sigma$ and homomorphism $\sigma$-homomorphisms.

Comment: It is pointed if and only if $\mathbf{A}$ is pointed.

Comment: (The “if” direction is easy and the “only if” direction needs the fact that algebraic categories always have initial and terminal objects.)

Comment: What will the 0 object be? I tried investigating the question on my own and checked the functor which sends everything to some 0 object in **A** and all morphisms to the identity morphism on that 0 object, but it didn't seem to be initial nor terminal, as any natural transformation k from another functor G, would have by what I figured have to satisfy k(X)=k(Y)G(g) for any objects X and Y and morphism g from X to Y in Top and similarly G(g)k(X)=k(Y) when considering natural transfomations from this functor to G.

Comment: @27182818284tropy yes, the 0-object in the functor category is indeed the functor taking constant value 0. the component at X of the unique transformation from G to 0 is the unique map of type  $GX \to 0$, and the equation you're stating does indeed hold. There's no contradiction.